# Using an object as a prototype

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why this code does not work?

```
PhoneNumber.prototype = Map;

var Map = {
    writeToDOM : function(container) {
        //DO STUFF HERE
    }   
};

PhoneNumber.writeToDOM(Container);
```

Is it not possible to reference an object in respect to an object's protype and use said object's functions? The reason I would want to do this is so I can use the Map variable on multiple objects rather than having to repeat the writeToDOM code for each object like this:

```
Object1.prototype.writeToDOM = function() {
    //DO STUFF HERE
}

Object2.prototype.writeToDOM = function() {
    //DO the exact same stuff as Object1
}
```

Comment: http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm

Comment: Can you tell, what the PhoneNumber object holds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
var Map;
PhoneNumber.prototype = Map;

Map = {
    writeToDOM : function(container) {
        //DO STUFF HERE
    }   
};

PhoneNumber.writeToDOM(Container);
```

That is, you are assigning `PhoneNumber.prototype` to `Map`, which currently contains `undefined`. Then you are reassigning `Map` to a new value, but not changing `PhoneNumber.prototype` at all.

---

If you simply assigned `Map` to the desired object before assigning the prototype to `Map`, you would be OK:

```
var Map = {
    writeToDOM : function(container) {
        //DO STUFF HERE
    }   
};

PhoneNumber.prototype = Map;

PhoneNumber.writeToDOM(Container);
```

Comment: All ok except last line: `writeToDOM` exist in `PhoneNumber.prototype`, not in `PhoneNumber`. You must call it as `PhoneNumber.prototype.writeToDOM(...)` or if `PhoneNumber` is a function as `new PhoneNumber().writeToDOM(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to variable declaration hoisting, what is actually happening when your code runs is this:

```
var Map; // = undefined;

PhoneNumber.prototype = Map;

Map = {
   writeToDOM : function(container) {
     //DO STUFF HERE
   }
};

PhoneNumber.writeToDOM(Container);
```

Regardless of where *you* put your `var` statement(s) JS treats them as if they were at the top of that scope, but doesn't assign the values until the line where you did so. So at the point where you try to use `Map` it is still undefined.

Move your `Map` assignment up to before `PhoneNumber.prototype = Map`.

Comment: `writeToDOM` exist in `PhoneNumber.prototype`, not in `PhoneNumber`. You cannot call `writeToDOM` as `PhoneNumber.writeToDOM(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
var Map = {
  writeToDOM: function() {
    // stuff
  }
}

var extend = function(obj, proto) {
  for(var k in proto) {
    obj.prototype[k] = proto[k];
  }
}

extend(Object1, Map);
extend(Object2, Map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
function PhoneNumber (){}
PhoneNumber.prototype = Map;

var Map = {
   writeToDOM : function() {
     console.log("test");
   }   
};


var instance = new PhoneNumber();
instance.writeToDOM();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per me it can be done without using prototype also.

```
var Map = {
    writeToDOM : function(container) {
       console.log("written to "+container); //container is string  
    }   
};
function PhoneNumber(name,no){
        var map=Map;
    this.name="user";
    this.no=100;
        return{
         toString:function(){
            return this.name+"-"+this.no;
           },
         writeToDOM:map.writeToDOM
         }
}
var phone1=new PhoneNumber("cham",100002);
console.log(phone1.writeToDOM("body"));
```

Answer (score -2):

Modify to this:

> var Map;
>   PhoneNumber.prototype = Map;
>
> Map = {
>       writeToDOM : function(container) {
>           //DO STUFF HERE
>       }    };
>
> PhoneNumber.writeToDOM(Container);

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this won't work. You have to assign the value to `Map` before you try to use that value.

Comment: yes, you are right! I mixed up 'by reference' and 'by sharing'. sorry for that. :-(.